# Set Integer Value of JavaFX TextField

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I have a set of JavaFX(8) TextFields that I would like to be pre-populated with the details of a model class. So far this is working fine;

```
String caseNotes;
caseNotes = selectedJob.getCaseNotes();
caseNotesArea.setText(caseNotes);
```

However, when I want to set the value to an integer it doesn't work, e.g;

```
Integer priorityPrompt;
priorityPrompt =  selectedJob.getPrioritySetting();
priorityField.setText(priorityPrompt);
```

What can I use instead of setText to set an Integer in the TextField instead of a String?

Comment: "_What can I use instead of setText to set an Integer in the TextField instead of a String?_" You don't. Just turn the Integer into a String first. `String.valueOf(int)`

Comment: Side note, I would like to know who read this question, thought to themselves "Ya, this question shows research effort", and then upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the signature if [`setText()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setText-java.lang.String-) method, that's accepting a Sttring. Not `integer`

```
public final void setText(String value)
```

Convert your `int` to String.

```
priorityField.setText(String.valueOf(priorityPrompt));
```